# how to check if element has this value or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

Here is my code i mixed up liquid code and js i got product handle but this if condition is not working i have  tag with attribute value still it shows not found can someone help me with this issue

```html
<a class="hidden_wrap" name="hidden_link" data-color="gold" data-stone="tiger-eye" data-handle="copy-of-joory-earrings-tiger-eye-gold
" style="appearance: auto;"> gold-tiger-eye   </a>

<script>
          var handle = "{{product.handle}}";
         if ($(`a[class='hidden_wrap'][data-handle='${handle}').length > 0) {
                    alert("found");
                  }else
                  {

              alert('not found');
          }
</script>
```

Comment: what error is shown in your console? but wouldn't you need quotes around your liquid: `var handle = '{{product.handle}}';` and you haven't closed the square bracket and tick quote of your selector

Comment: it  shows undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try With This,
Use backtick for **product.handle** and also for html content in jquery. :)

& Remove White Space after **copy-of-joory-earrings-tiger-eye-gold**.

```
<script>
     var handle = `{{product.handle}}`;
     if ($(`a[class='hidden_wrap'][data-handle=${handle}`).length > 0) {
          alert("found");
     }
     else{
          alert('not found');
     }
</script>
```

Comment: still got not found

Comment: @vidit let me try another way for you. :)

Comment: $('a[class="hidden_wrap"][data-handle="copy-of-joory-earrings-tiger-eye-gold"]') it shows length 0  but  when i use $('a[class="hidden_wrap"][data-color="gold"] it shows length 1

Comment: Buddy @vidit I found Why you got 0 in copy-of-joory-earrings-tiger-eye-gold. Because Buddy in your <a tag line space is there after gold word please check it and remove that space and run it. I tried this and i got length 1 in copy-of-joory-earrings-tiger-eye-gold this. :)

Comment: GOt it Thank You for help

Answer (score 0):

Try this
You can directly get the value by attribute using jquery.

```
<script>
var handleAttr = $(".hidden_wrap").attr("data-handle");
if(handleAttr){
alert("found");
}else{
alert("not found");
}
</script>
```

Thanks.